# Python - Intersectiing strings

Tags: python, string, intersection

Trying to write a for function that takes two strings and returns the characters that intersect in the order that they appear in the first string.

Here's what I tried:

```
def strIntersection(str1, str2):
    for i in str1:
        str3 = ''
        str3 = str3.join(i for i in str1 if i in str2 not in str3)
    return str3

str1 = 'asdfasdfasfd'
str2 = 'qazwsxedc'

strIntersection(str1,str2)

=> 'asdasdasd'
```

however I only want the the intersection characters to appear once and in order of the first string ie. 'asd'

Can anyone help?

I've found some similar problems on other forums but the solutions all seem to involve lists whereas I'd like my output to be a string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for occurances the other way around to get the order under control, and don't emit characters you've already emitted:

```
def strIntersection(s1, s2):
  out = ""
  for c in s1:
    if c in s2 and not c in out:
      out += c
  return out
```

Sure you could re-write it to be a list comprehension, but I find this easier to understand.

For your test data, we get:

```
>>> strIntersection('asdfasdfasfd' , 'qazwsxedc')
'asd'
```

Comment: Thanks! It certainly is easier to understand. I realize now that I was complicating it by trying to use ''join()

Comment: `''.join` is idiomatic and not complicated at all. Using it in a loop, however, misses the point. Actually, the for-loop in the OP code is completely useless; it simply causes the real work - `str3 = str3.join(i for i in str1 if i in str2 not in str3)` to be performed multiple times, with the same result each time, and the result being thrown away each time but the last.

Comment: You can't actually rewrite this particular algorithm to be a list comprehension - at least not without invoking some very dubious undocumented stuff - because the filtering step `c in s2 and c not in out` depends on the partial results up to this point, which aren't made accessible (except via very dubious undocumented stuff).

Comment: I just commented that replacing `out` with a list would speed things up, but then did some timeit tests and determined that they didn't, so I removed my old comment. My timings show that this solution used 10.7 usec per loop, Karls solution used 16.7 usec per loop and my modified `out = []` and `return "".join(out)` solution used 18.5 usec per loop.

Comment: For these particular strings, or for what test data? A set-based approach would probably require fairly long strings to show an advantage.

Answer (score 9):

You can use python sets http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set to do this, like so:

```
>>> set("asdfasdfasfd") & set("qazwsxedc")
set(['a', 's', 'd'])
```

Answer (score 7):

You want a string consisting of the unique characters that are common to `str1` and `str2`, in the order they appear in `str1`.

Uniqueness and commonality imply set operations: that is, we're looking for the set of characters that appear in both str1 and str2. A set is fundamentally unordered, but we can re-order the data by sorting the characters according to their "index" of first occurrence in `str1`. Then it's a simple matter of creating a string from the sorted sequence.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
''.join(sorted(set(str1) & set(str2), key = str1.index))
```

Answer (score 2):

easiest is to use sets in python

```
>>> a='asdfasdfasfd'
>>> b='qazwsxedc'
>>> set(a).intersection(b)
set(['a', 's', 'd'])
```

Comment: This replicates existing answers and does not provide the sorting that OP requires.

Comment: Do we need to convert string object to set to do comparison?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your current script should do it if you fix the typo on the fourth line:

```
str3 = str3.join(i for i in str1 if i in str2 not in str3)
```

should be

```
str3 = str3.join(i for i in str1 if i in str2 and i not in str3)
```

I wouldn't recommend using a set for this simpy because they don't guarantee order.  Your script is also likely to be faster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what OP actually meant was `(i for i in str1 if i in str2 and i not in str3)`. Except this doesn't work because the `str3` that needs to be compared against hasn't been constructed yet. He's got his logic confused by attempting to use both the for loop and the comprehension. As for performance, I would certainly expect `set`-based approaches to be much faster for long strings.

Comment: @Karl: Yes you're right, I'll update my answer.  But comparing with str3 shouldn't be a problem since it only needs to check the part which has already been constructed.

Comment: The problem is that `str3` **isn't** "the part which has already been constructed". Either you execute this code in a loop or you don't. If you don't, then `str3` will give an UnboundLocalError - you're trying to refer to the thing that you're assigning to. If you do, then having a `join` and a comprehension makes no sense, since you only want to consider the current character vs. the already-found intersecting characters, not the entire string.

Comment: @Karl: I'm really not awake today! I missed both the `str3 = ''` and the `str3.join(...)` when reading it.  I was think it was in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def str_intersection(str1, str2):
    common_letters = set(str1) & set(str2)
    str3 = ''
    for c in str1:
        if (c in common_letters) and (c not in str3):
            str3 += c
    return str3
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers help, however, you may need to ignore or not ignore the orders. It may be important, especially finding misspellings. Here more sophisticated version of the function for finding string intersection:

```
def str_intersection(str_left, str_right, ignore_order = True ):
    common_letters = set(str_left) & set(str_right)
    str_intersected = ''
    for c in str_left:
        if (c in common_letters) and (c not in str_intersected):
            str_intersected += c
    if ignore_order:
        pass
    else:
        if str_intersected in str_left and str_intersected in str_right:
            return str_intersected
        else:
            return None
    return str_intersected
```

If you run `str_intersection("AB","XAB")` result will be `AB`. **But main handicap of this way** is the result of `str_intersection("god","dog")` will be `god`. If you want to get nothing use this function like this: `str_intersection("god", "dog", ignore_order=False)` in that case result will be `None` because *god* and *dog* share the same characters but the order is different. I hope this sophisticated  may help you.